# Scope returns every item in the association if it cannot find an item that matches the scope's criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope

I have a simple scope:

```
scope :named, ->(passed_name) { find_by(name: passed_name) }
```

If the scope finds an entry with the requested name, then it returns the entry as expected:

```
@post1 = @user.posts.create(name: "My Post")
@post2 = @user.posts.create(name: "Some Post")
@post3 = @user.posts.create(name: "Some Other Post")
@user.posts.named("My Post") # => returns @post1
```

If, however, an entry with the requested name is not found, then it returns every item in the association:

```
@post2 = @user.posts.create(name: "Some Post")
@post3 = @user.posts.create(name: "Some Other Post")
@user.posts.named("My Post") # => returns association with @post2 and @post3, not the expected nil
```

Is this intended behavior? And either way, is there something I can do to get nil instead of the full association?

Answer (score 1):

[Looks like](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13647) this is how the Rails developers want things.

Since scopes are out of the question, I had to take a different approach. Within the User model, I created a method:

```
def post_named(name)
  posts.find_by(name: name)
end
```

Not quite as elegant, but it works at least.